# Warning: Error in loadNamespace: there is no package called ‘leafletsector’

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am trying to reverse engineer an R code which is currently running on a Linux Server.
I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: Error in loadNamespace: there is no package called ‘leafletsector’
90: <Anonymous>
```

I tried installing the package leafletsector, but it isn't available for R-3.4 or R-3.5.

I am running this code on Windows 7.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure `leafletsector` is actually a library and not a function?

Comment: How did you install this package on Win7?